# CountourPlot3D problem when intersecting semiplanes

Tags: graphics3d, mesh, intersection, plotting

I have the following code:

```
RegionPlot3D[x + y + z <= 3 && x + z <= 1, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, {z, 0, 2} , BoxRatios -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

To get the following picture seen from below:

[image]

As you can see, 3 diferent lines appear when I'm just intersecting 2 semiplanes.

I have tried with different mesh options but i couldn't find the key to this problem.

Comment: add the option `PlotPoints -> 200`?

Comment: or the options `PlotPoints -> 60`, and `MaxRecursion -> 7`?

Comment: @klgr Using `PlotPoints -> 100` does the trick, but it takes a little bit longer. But thanks I didnt't know that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plane, we can decreasing the `MaxCellMeasure` instead of increasing it.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   x + y + z <= 3 && x + z <= 1 && 0 <= x <= 3 && 0 <= y <= 3 && 
    0 <= z <= 2, {x, y, z}];
RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: `MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity`